# The result of FD_ISSET without calling `select`

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I'm learning socket programming using book `Unix Network Programming`. Here are two pieces of code from this book:

[image]

[image]

As we can see, it calls `FD_ISSET` after `FD_SET` without calling `select` function between them, what's the result? Will it be `true` if `sockfd` is writable?

PS: the source code http://www.masterraghu.com/subjects/np/introduction/unix_network_programming_v1.3/ch16lev1sec2.html

Comment: `FD_SET` and `FD_ISSET` have no intrinsic connection to any socket.. They operate on the set provided. It's up to the code to set those correctly either through a `select` call or some other logic as seems to be done in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are 30 missing lines between the two snippets, how do we know that `select` isn't called there?

Besides that, the `select` function isn't doing anything special, it just clears descriptors from the sets.

If you call `FD_SET(sockfd, &wset)` directly followed by `FD_ISSET(sockfd, &wset)` then the `FD_ISSET` macro will simply evaluate to "true" (a non-zero integer value).

Comment: Thanks. I posted the link to the source code in the question, the missing 30 lines could be found there.

Comment: The `select` clears the flags, then wait for the file descriptors to be ready and re-set the flags. Is this right?

Comment: @xingbin Exactly what `select` does depends on its implementation, but in a way yes that's correct.

Answer (score 3):

`FD_SET` just sets a bit in a bit mask and `FD_ISSET` checks this bit. These calls don't care if this bit represents a file descriptor or not, it is just an integer. If there is nothing in between these calls which manipulates the bit mask (i.e. no call of `select`) then the result of `FD_ISSET` reflects exactly what was set with `FD_SET`.